# How to run with mocha and node-inspector parallel with grunt tasks

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, node-inspector

At the moment I am running tests with simple-mocha grunt task. I want to debug the code while running the tests. How would I do that with grunt?

```
    simplemocha: {
        options: {
            globals: ['expect'],
            timeout: 3000,
            ignoreLeaks: false,
            ui: 'bdd',
            reporter: 'tap'
        },
        all: {
            src: ['test/*.js']
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of achieving this. One is using this grunt task as a step of your own test-debug task (does exactly the same as your simplemocha task but runs grunt-debug first): https://github.com/burnnat/grunt-debug

You must enable the plugin by adding this to your Gruntfile:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-debug');
```

and then prepend `debug` before running your existing task, in console:

```
grunt debug simplemocha
```

Or, you could invoke `nodejs --debug` passing the main grunt script and arguments. A convenient way to do that in Linux bash would be `nodejs --debug $(which grunt) simplemocha`.

Comment: How would I do it with grunt-debug. could you give code examples?

Comment: Sorry @PrashanFernando, I had pasted the wrong link. I added the right one and a small code snippet that is exactly what they advice doing. Also, you could define a task alias to call it directly (see http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks).